# Some Os are killing Foreground service is it normal or exception?

Tags: android, android-studio

My app is working fine in many devices but in few devices os is killing it  I want to know is it normal or exception and  how to resolve it?

Comment: Did these devices enable something like Battery Mode?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine may be  i have not checked it if yes then how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Are these being started whilst the app is in the background? If so you can only start a foreground service from the background in some [special use cases](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions). The docs state that the thing to do here is use [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) instead.

As the Android OS is customized by different hardware manufacturers (e.g. Samsung etc) then its possible that services get killed off for various reasons - most likely to be battery saving related.